# How do I query the title (or handle?) of post meta fieldset (created with Simple Fields Plugin)

Tags: custom-field, post-meta

I am having a heck of a time trying to retrieve the  title (or handle?) of my custom post meta fields.

I am using the slmple fields plugin.  http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-fields/
(as I understand it, this just makes use of 'normal' post-meta stuff.

I have tried the `simple_fields_get_post_group_values()` function provided by plugin, as well as the following code I found in the WP codex, to no avail:

```
<?php $checkit = get_post_custom( 22 ); 
print_r($checkit);?>
```

I have also tried searching the database for the phrases themselves within phpMyAdmin, and they don't appear to be there, which is perplexing.

I'm pretty new to all this stuff, so I am sure I am missing something obvious ;-)

I would be extremely grateful for any advice or help anyone could offer.

---

I've circled (badly) the info I am trying to query.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values you have circled are not part of the custom fields. They are part of the configuration data of Simple Fields. You can find them in the dadabase in table wp_options in the row with option_name=simple_fields_groups. Field option_value contains a string of serialized data.

You can read the option with WP function get_option(). It is deserialize automatically. Use var_dump() or a plugin like [SM Debug Bar](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/sm-debug-bar/) to display the content.

Comment: Hey thanks!  I'll check this out later today and select the answer when I get it running

Comment: Worked like a charm!  Weird that I searched the database and didn't find this.  I guesse I screwed up somewhere ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Simple Fields is a bit complicated as it does not allow to set the name of the custom field variables. It also does not support select lists where value and displayed option differ.

I've moved to plugin [Just Custom Fields](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/just-custom-fields/). It has a very comfortable user interface. The only disadvantage is a missing export/import function. Accessing the custom fields in a template file is the standard WP mechanism.

Other plugins are (untested):

- Advanced Custom Fields (export/import option available?)
- Meta Box (configuration is done in a file, thus no export/import option necessary)
- Magic Fields (does not differ between value and displayed option in select elements)
- Easy Custom Fields (integrates in functions.php, needs programming knowledge)
- More Fields (does not differ between value and displayed option in select elements, the optional access restrictions should not be used)